# Add Multiple Web Apps to App Service Environment

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-app-service-plans

Have recently started using App Service Environments and need a little help. Have created an ASE and added a Wep App to it, the Web APP has it's own service plan and resource group. I now need to add a new Web APP to the same ASE, but this Web APP will have a different service plan and resource group.

When I try this I get a deployment error saying the following "Not enough available reserved instance servers to satisfy this request". Any suggestions as to how I can resolve this, I have looed around and can't seem to find a solution that works.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to scale up your App Service Environment first. Navigate to your App Service Environment details in portal and scale the number of machines up (you probably have the default configuration now, which is 2 small workers). That will allocate more capacity and you will be able to use them for your new plans.

One thing to mention - one worker is always used for high-availability purposes so you have a guarantee that your sites are up during outages/services upgrades etc. So if you have 2 workers, only 1 can be used for your sites and 1 is spare. If you have 3 workers, 2 can be used for your apps/plans.

It is always 1 spare worker per up to 20 workers; so if you have let's say 40 workers, you will have 2 spare machine and 38 will be available for apps/plans.

Comment: Have scaled up the ASE but am still only allowed to have a single service plan per worker pool.

Comment: Can you provide the error message or what do you see when you try to create another service plan in that worker pool?